# Tag Stats and Info Pages not accessible for sponsored tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

On Stack overflow the "stats" and "info" tabs for tags both seem to have disappeared. I've just looked at the [C++ tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and there is still a link to stats there but for [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) there is an advert in it's place as it is a sponsored tag meaning no direct link.

I presume this might be unintentional hence the "bug" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This is actually intentional, that section is prime real-estate, we would have to give up tag sponsorship if we were to stay consistent. The thing is people already paid us for that space, we can not just take it away.</strike>

We also do not want to flood users with half a page of info when all they want to do is answer a question.

This was completed a while back

Comment: Understood, but the user experience is rather jarring...

Answer (score 4):

The `stats` and `info` tabs are still there.  If you click the tag and then click the about link on the right hand side.

[image]

You can then access the tabs at the top
[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that was there. Still a bit of a mission to get to them on sponsored tags though!