# Adding a link to Android.SE on the Android tag wiki?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

Would there be any chance of adding a link to Android.SE to the [Android wiki tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android) on SO to direct those wanting to ask Android user questions, not developer questions? Similarly could be applied to iphone/apple.SE.

Is it even editable since it is a sponsored tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69276/how-to-direct-android-devs-on-so-to-the-android-enthusiasts-beta-site

Comment: I disagree with this being a dupe. This is a specific request for the tag wiki.

Comment: Whoops, forgot that gary also posted it

Answer (score 1):

The tag wiki is editable, and you are able to place a link in there. It's [pretty pitiful right now](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info), so it could use some touching up. I think adding a link to the Stack Exchange site could be useful, summat like...

> For questions about developing on the Android, ask them here tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android). For questions about using the Android, check out...

Sponsored tags display instead of the excerpt on the actual questions listing, but it doesn't interfere with the wiki itself or its content. Indirectly, this cuts into the visibility of your link, and makes the excerpt all but useless during the period of sponsorship (Android seems to have had a pretty long one).

Comment: Perhaps it needs to show both the sponsored portion AND the wiki tag part too?  Because the wiki tag page gets NO visibility unless you click on the small about link on the right side of the Android tag on the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android page

Comment: @Bryan Allowing tag wikis to be shown underneath means anywhere between competing against the sponsorship (they paid for visibility so they get priority) and pushing down the questions (no one likes humongous headers obscuring content, which can happen if it's too stacked). I think there's a request on Meta, though, for some kind of medium between tag wikis and sponsorship.

Comment: at the very least it should have the links at the bottom of the sponsorship tag like any other tag "about the java tag | faq | top users | hot answers | new answers | synonyms "

Comment: @Bryan [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62221/tag-stats-and-info-pages-not-accessible-for-sponsored-tags) is so far the only report I've found on Meta on the subject. I don't see a specific request for adding the "linkbar" beneath the sponsorship and simply skimp on the excerpt. You can try proposing that as a suggestion (ideally as a separate question).