# Is it acceptable to use a tag-wiki to suggest a question with that tag belongs on another site?

Tags: support, etiquette, stackexchange-2.0, tag-wiki

Many of the questions on Stack Overflow with [hosting](/questions/tagged/hosting) belong on Pro Webmasters or on Server Fault. Is it OK to edit the tag wiki to say "if you've used this tag consider putting your question on these sites..."? There would also need to be a quick explanation of how to decide which of the two.

Comment: What would be a good example of an an on-topic question containing the [hosting] tag on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: "I'm implementing the admin console for a hosting service. How can I..."

Comment: @Ernest: Hm, nothing to do with hosting, really (it's a tangential concept in your example). I thought you were going to say something like, "How can I host this component in..." or somesuch.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill Good example. I wondered that myself, but couldn't think of anything. I doubt we'll get that many though.

Comment: If a tag requires a lot of explanation to deduce it's proper usage, it's probably not a very good tag to begin with.  What would you suggest for this tag?

Comment: I think the tag itself is fine, because people know what it means. What they aren't understanding is that there are better places for that sort of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is acceptable. See [the case with Android Enthusiasts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69927/adding-a-link-to-android-se-on-the-android-tag-wiki) and [android](/questions/tagged/android).

> Android is Google's software stack for mobile devices that includes an operating system, middleware and key applications. For non-developer questions, see http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite appropriate to me. Many tag wikis contain instructions about how to use a tag and when to consider using additional or alternate tags; redirecting to another SE site seems a natural extension of that.